# Check if a function is created by useCallback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have hooks that accept functions as arguments. If the functions change unnecessarily, then it could cause extra re-renders. I want to ensure that the functions are wrapped with `useCallback`.

I.e. here's a simplified version:

```
function useApi({ onSuccess }) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && !isUseCallback(onSuccess)) {
    throw new Error();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(...)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(onSuccess);
  }, [onSuccess]);
}
```

If `onSuccess` changes unnecessarily, then it'll call the API unnecessarily. Is it possible to have the function `isUseCallback`? I think I'd have to write a custom `useCallback` that wraps React's `useCallback`.

Comment: No, useCallback don’t mark the produced function in any special way. And the way you implement the guard looks kinda wierd.

Comment: So there’s necessary change and unnecessary change of onSuccess. Can you first define the qualifier? What quality is deemed necessary/unnecessary?

Comment: I think that the answer is to make sure that onSuccess is wrapped in useCallback and make sure that its dependencies don't change. Any objects or functions will fail equality (===) checks unless they are wrapped in useMemo or useCallback respectively.

Comment: You could adapt [useWhyDidYouUpdate](https://usehooks.com/useWhyDidYouUpdate/), but would have to move the `if()` inside the hook (which can't be called conditionally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using Typescript:

```
type UseCallback<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> =
  ((...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>) & { __IS_USE_CALLBACK?: undefined };

declare function useCallback<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  callback: T,
  deps: ReadonlyArray<any>,
): UseCallback<T>;
```

.

```
function useApi(onSuccess: UseCallback<() => any>): any;

useApi(() => {}); // Error
useApi(useCallback(() => {})); // No error
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhAwgQwDaoEbIMYGsA8AKlBAB7AQB2AJnFABQB0zyATgOZwBcUylIAbQC6ASigBeAHy9+08QCgoDJiw7coABTbIAthAqs4RSWKlQASvoCurSoXARjYgGRQA3lAD6ngJIBlTxg-AFFPRABBABlIgCFwxABpAH4eKxoIADMAS0oIaigAXwBueXlqCGxUNmgMtOxgLIB7SigrBBR0LDwiEnIqWgZmRjZOHj5BUQlpccl6RShsNEwcXB5CABp58rB1S2RqZtQQcNZWZBB8Gc2RHngkJa6CQkkS+VrKeqaWtohwsCz6M0-FZsNgIHB1HcOstuvRTNNZDcZCB3PMlECQWCIXCSsVSj8-gC4VN3AUREUoAB6SlQYKnRqseQE-70H7Qx70YlmNwFdZQYQiclUmkAOUaJHprCAA

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the callback in a `useRef()` to ensure the `useEffect()` callback has a reference to the most recent `onSuccess`:

```js
function useApi({ onSuccess }) {
  const ref = useRef();

  ref.current = onSuccess;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(...)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(val => ref.current(val));
  }, []);
}
```

It's important that you write `.then(val => ref.current(val))` instead of just `.then(ref.current)` so that the property access `ref.current` doesn't occur until the `fetch()` resolves. That way `ref.current` is equal to the most recent `onSuccess` passed to `useApi()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useCallback` from npm package `rely-use-callback` instead origin useCallback.
This package contains `RelyCallback` type, that can be used in type checking

For example:

```js
import { useCallback, RelyCallback } from 'rely-use-callback';

const handleClick = useCallback(() => {}, []);
...

const useSomethinkToDoOnEffect = (  
   todoFunction: RelyCallback<() => void>
) => {  
    useEffect(() => {  
        todoFunction()  
    }, [ todoFunction ]);  
}

const MemoizedComponent:FC<{  
   onClick: RelyCallback<() => void>
}> = memo(() => <ChildComponent onClick={onClick} />)
```

More about motivation you can read https://github.com/vkruglikov/rely-use-callback#-motivation